# Can't take screenshot after changing Wordpress theme on win 10

Tags: wordpress, themes

I installed wordpress on my win10, and I want to change the default theme , but I have a problem: the theme does not show the screenshot, however the  default theme does!
    Look the following :
- [default theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx5n2.png)
[image]

- [showing the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVc5k.png)
  [image]
- [using theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNYC9.png)
  [image]
- [not showing the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywpJu.png)
  [image]

So the reason is? 
I am looking forward to your answer! Thanks!

Comment: What's the issue, you can't change the theme or you can't take screenshots of the new theme. Please be more specific.

Comment: the latter,when i change the theme ,i can't take the screenshot

Comment: Mark, what does 'take' the screenshot' mean to you?  Do we have a language issue here? Where are you when that 404 is showing? Homepage? Does that theme work ?  You have to provide clearer description of what actually the problem is.   It looks like the problem is there's a 404 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Sheryl means that the preview image is not showing.  See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27427/wordpress-theme-preview-image.

Create the screenshot yourself and place it in the theme/child theme folder and name it screenshot.png

Comment: "Shery means", it's not clear what you're talking about... ?

Comment: You're right. a)  It's a Mark, not Sheryl.  And b) still guessing what 'take the screenshot' means.  On relooking at Mark's screenshots, it seems that the theme is not working? homepage giving a '404'?